My request cookie not working on server but works locally (Azure Web Appservices)
I am using my web cookie from chrome to log onto a web using python requests. This works very fine on localhost http://127.0.0.1:8000/ but when I deploy this on to azure App Services, this does not work any more and shows "WARNING: Login Failed!!"
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    def __init__(self, link, text):
        self.link = link
        self.cookie = 'my_cookies'
        self.user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36'
        self.text = text

    def login(self, url):
        headers = {
            'User-Agent': self.user_agent,
            'Cookie': self.cookie,
        }
        session = requests.Session()
        response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
        response.text.encode('utf-8')
        if response.status_code != 200:
            print('WARNING: Login Failed!!')
        return response

I tried to change cookies and inbond IP but still get WARNING: Login Failed!!

error code is: 403

Check if the website has IP blocking or rate-limiting rules that affecting Azure's outbound IP range. If that is the issue use a proxy or contact the website admin to whitelist Azure IPs.


Scrapy's session handling is independent of the requests module. You are using requests.Session() inside a Scrapy spider, but Scrapy has its own mechanisms for handling requests, sessions, and cookies.

It's better to handle cookies and session management using Scrapy's built-in tools rather than mixing requests into the code. Scrapy provides a cookie parameter in Request objects.
Code:
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "my_spider"

    def __init__(self, link, text):
        self.link = link
        self.cookies = {'my_cookies': 'cookie_value'}
        self.user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36'
        self.text = text

    def start_requests(self):
        headers = {
            'User-Agent': self.user_agent,
        }
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=self.link, 
            headers=headers, 
            cookies=self.cookies, 
            callback=self.parse
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        # Process the login response here
        if response.status != 200:
            self.logger.warning('Login Failed!!')
        else:
            self.logger.info('Login successful.')
        # Continue with your parsing logic here

Local domain is different and azure domain is different Check that the cookie is valid for the Azure domain. Try retrieving a fresh cookie that is valid for the Azure domain.
Logged-in:
2024-09-23 12:45:32 - INFO - Attempting login to [testappt-c4g0abb6e3ffhkff.eastus-01.azurewebsites.net] https://testappt-c4g0abb6e3ffhkff.eastus-01.azurewebsites.net/login with headers: {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36', 'Cookie': 'cookie_name=value; other_cookie=value2'}
2024-09-23 12:45:34 - INFO - Response Status Code: 200
2024-09-23 12:45:34 - INFO - Response Cookies: <RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie sessionid=abcdef1234567890 for .example.com/>]>
2024-09-23 12:45:34 - INFO - Response Headers: {'Date': 'Mon, 23 Sep 2024 12:45:34 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Set-Cookie': 'sessionid=abcdef12339402890; expires=Mon, 30-Sep-2024 12:45:34 GMT; HttpOnly; Path=/'}
2024-09-23 12:45:34 - INFO - Login successful.


hi @Suresh thanks for your recommendation, I am actually trying use my personal cookie from local chrome to access a public web [call it X] from azure server. Do you suggest me to change a domain because this default domain might be blocked by the public web [X]? also I am unable to check X's server side log :)
